# Several troubles making simple object inspector in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am javascript and React newbie, so I am still a little bit confused by thinking in React concept.

I am trying to make simple object inspector in React.

Here is property row element:

```
class PropertyRow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       propertyName: this.props.propertyName,
       propertyValue: this.props.propertyValue
    };
    alert(this.props.propertyName + " evoked in constructor");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.propertyName} = {this.props.propertyValue}</div>
     // <div>{this.state.propertyName} = {this.state.propertyValue}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

here in the component PropertyRows I am trying to read all properties of an object dynamically.

```
class PropertyRows extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.createProRows = this.createProRows.bind(this);
  }

  createProRows(obj) {
    const propArr = [];
      for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        const val = obj[key];
        propArr.push(<PropertyRow propertyName={key} propertyValue={val} />); 
      }
    return propArr;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.createProRows(this.props.obj)}</div>;
  }
}
```

And here I test this marvelous code

```
class Express extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      soldiers: 0,
      captain:'John Maverick'
    };
    this.doClick = this.doClick.bind(this);
  }

  doClick() {
    const obj = {
      soldiers: this.state.soldiers + 1,
      country:'Australia' //add new property
    };
    this.setState(obj);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.doClick}>
        <PropertyRows obj={this.state} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Express />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

When you click  on the text, you will see incrementing "soldiers" property by one. The code is buggy and I do not understand why, or perhaps I do, but I have not absolutely no idea, what how to solve it in React metalanguage.

1. I would expect, that dynamically created array of `<PropertyRow propertyName={key} propertyValue={val}/>` would be nice way to browse object properties. But it seems, that the rendered HTML DOM objects are not destroyed and recreated. They are mysteriously reattached, when the new object in the `doClick` function is to be expressed.

Furthermore

2. When create another object in `doClick`, the property `obj.captain` is still there (in the browser window), probably because the underlying HTML DOM elements are not destroyed. Adding new property `country: 'Australia'` seems to work OK.
3. When I call `<PropertyRow propertyName={key} propertyValue={val}/>` the second time I would expect, that constructor would be fired, because it is created and pushed in the new array. But it is not. It is fired only for the new property `country: 'Australia'`

It seems, that I have to somehow destroy rendered HTML DOM elements in order to force react to recreate them. But how? 
Or is there another way?

I deeply apologize for this long text. I hope it's not so complicated to read.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

`delete obj.captain` doesn't do anything because there's no `captain` key in `obj`. `captain` key exists in `this.state`, and deleting it from it is discouraged because React state is conventionally immutable.

The use of `this.state` together with `this.setState` may potentially result in race condition, [state updater](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) function should be used instead.

It should be:

```
  doClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      soldiers: state.soldiers + 1,
      country:'Australia',
      captain: undefined  
    }));
  }
```

The problem with `PropertyRow` is that it processes props once in constructor. `PropertyRow` constructor is fired only once because the component has been already mounted and now it is only updated on new props (here's [illustrative diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) of React lifecycle hooks).

If a state is supposed to derive from received props, [`getDerivedStateFromProps` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) should be used, it maps a state from props before initial render and next updates. In this case a state is not needed because state properties and props don't differ. It's enough to have:

```
class PropertyRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.propertyName} = {this.props.propertyValue}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

And `PropertyRow` could be rewritten as functional component because it doesn't benefit from being a class.

Comment: Oh, I see "delete obj.captain" is obvious mistake. I removed it. I will follow your suggestions to understand it more deeply...